# How to organize and minify lots of javascript files?

Tags: javascript, php, minify, bundling-and-minification

I have a project written on PHP and JavaScript.

For example, I have two main JavaScript files
main1.js and main2.js.

They use the same functions, and I want to extract the functions to lib.js etc.

On develop environment it's more useful to use 3 different files, but on production i'd like to have 2 minifyied files with lib.js included.

I want to see changes on dev immediately without any preprocessing, and I want to use some preprocessing on production.

For example I can write a javascript function require(filename) that loads needed js file, but how to tell minifyer to include the file inline on production?

Comment: can use cofee script.

Comment: there are many js compress tools available . try http://jscompress.com/ or [YUI Compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/)

Comment: 3 != lots. Is the goal to shrink request size or to combine js files?

Comment: both. It's going to be lots of js files, and need combine and minify them when deploing

Comment: cofeescript is not compatible to javascript. I dont like its syntax

Comment: just because you do not like its syntax does not make it compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/)

and also into creating `makefiles`

you can also compress CSS with YUI Compressor

Comment: I hate YUI Compressor, but I suspect it's because it is the only minifier I've used and I hate minification. Is there really a performance benefit to shrinking a request by 10-20kb at this point?

Comment: it depends on how you like to keep your code organised, using YUI Compressor I have 10+ JavaScript files going in to one, keeping my code organised and easy to manage. Also if you have 10+ requests to the server the overhead will be a lot more than 10-20kb: depending on how many requests your browser can handle at once you might end up with multiple files blocking the other files downloading until they're finished. Coincidently, that's why small images sometimes get put on a sprite-sheet too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using netbeans then you can use the plugin from here

[Plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49666/js-css-minify-compress)

Also you can use

[minifycss](http://www.minifycss.com/)

[YUI](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/)

For online compression

Answer (score 0):

`Coffee Script` is used for caching the js files on browser side. It create a single js file from all files, and minify the resultant code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try these for minify javascript and css online.

> http://minify.avivo.si/#results
>
> http://gtmetrix.com/minify-javascript-and-css.html
>
> http://www.minifycss.com/